# Axios - how can I conditionally append fields

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, axios

I have this Axios patch but I only want to include the last three, if the hyperlink_column isn't null. How can I do this?

Thanks,

Mick

```
  axios.patch('/' + self.table + '/' + self.rowId,{

                name: self.name,
                SQL:self.SQL,
                area_id:self.area_id,
                report_type_id:self.report_type_id,
                mode:self.mode,
                database_connection_id:self.database_connection_id,
                pagination: self.pagination,
                show_export_buttons : self.show_export_buttons,
                filters : self.filters,
                description : self.description,
                category_id : self.category_id,

                hyperlink_column : self.hyperlink_column,
                linked_report : self.linked_report,
                link_parameter : self.link_parameter,
```

Answer (score 0):

Since by the look of it, it looks like the second parameter is an object, so one way of doing it, would be to invoke a function as the second parameter and passing your data inside `self` as an argument. The function will then check if  `self.hyperlink_column` exists and then return an object accordingly. like this

[Repl](https://repl.it/JjeJ/3)

PS : This is done using closure.